# How to reorder records (SortOrder column) after deleting a record in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering what the most efficient way is to reorder my records after I delete a record. Basically I have something like (ItemID, SortOrder). So when I delete an item, the SortOrder column will no longer be incremental. I want to re number sort order so that the numbers are incremental again.

I was thinking maybe I could do this with the RANK feature...but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: What does it matter if they are incremental? They will still be in the right order.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using something that supports T-SQL (i.e. not Compact Edition), then this should work.

Assuming your table is named `Item` and the orders are currently incremental (no gaps),

```
declare @SortOrder int

select @SortOrder = SortOrder from Item where ItemID = @ItemID

update Item set SortOrder = SortOrder - 1 where SortOrder > @SortOrder

delete Item where ItemID = @ItemID
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a periodic tidy up then the following would work to "fix" all gaps.

#### Some test data

```
SELECT *
INTO   #TEST
FROM   (SELECT 1, 1, 1
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 2, 1, 3
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 3, 1, 4
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 4, 2, 2
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 5, 2, 3
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 6, 2, 4)H(PK, ItemID, SortOrder)
```

#### The code

```
WITH Tidied
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID 
                                       ORDER BY SortOrder) AS NewSortOrder
         FROM   #TEST)
UPDATE Tidied
SET    SortOrder = NewSortOrder
```